# Selecting values from 2 columns that both are IDs of another tables rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say i have:

Table1:

```
ID    Name
1     Ann
2     Mike
3     Stan  
4     Kyle
```

Table2:

```
Pair ID    Person1ID    Person2ID
1          1            2
2          3            4
```

I want to select pairs, but with names instead of IDs, so this would be the output:

```
1    Ann    Mike
2    Stan   Kyle
```

I imagine a simple:

```
inner join Table1 on Table1.ID=Table2.Person1ID
```

won't work, because I want both of them, not only one.

I'm pretty new to SQL so i'm sorry if there is a simple answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to join twice and use alias to diference the tables

```
SELECT t2.PairID, A.Name, B.Name
FROM Table2 t2
JOIN Table1 A
  ON t2.Person1ID = A.ID
JOIN Table1 B
  ON t2.Person2ID = B.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join sub query like below:

```
Select p.PairID, p.Name, q.Name
from 
    (Select t2.PairID, t1.Name
     from Table1 t1 inner join Table2 t2
     on t1.ID = t2.Person1ID) p
inner join   
    (Select t2.PairID, t1.Name
     from Table1 t1 inner join Table2 t2
     on t1.ID = t2.Person2ID) q
on p.PairID = q.PairID
```

See the result here in the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d20bf98/21).

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza No doubt, your answer is better. But do you think, it's not an another solution? I just tried to solve this in another way. Thanks

Comment: I just think you over complicate the problem.Isnt really a different way is just over doing the same.